# Why doesn't the id of a list change even if the list is moved in memory?

Tags: python, list, memory

As I know, dynamic arrays (list in Python) move in memory when its size reaches its capacity. And as far as I know the id of an object corresponds to its memory address.

But when appending values to a list many times, its id doesn't change (so it stays in the same place in memory).

Why?

```
a = []

print(id(a))  # 2539296050560

for i in range(1_000_000):
    a.append(i)

print(id(a))  # 2539296050560
```

Comment: `for i in range(1_000_000):` I don't think it's a right `for` loop. Maybe remove the underscores?

Comment: The id is guaranteed stable for the lifetime of the object (at the Python language level, not just the CPython implementation level):  https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id.

Comment: @BrainFlooder the _underscores_ are valid in numeric literals.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I didn't know that, thanks.

Comment: 10 years of Python and I didn't know that you could write integer literals with underscores.

Comment: @timgeb since 3.6: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#integer-literals

Comment: Literally even I did not knew it, thank you alot @jonrsharpe :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making a confusion between the address of the list (what is the *id* in CPython) and the address of the *data*. Under the hood and in CPython, a list is an object that contains a pointer to the beginning of its data. So when you extend the list, the data will be moved in memory but the list object will not, allowing it to keep a fix id - which is required per the language.